# How to place a very large image (Size) in a document?

Tags: graphics, floats

I am trying to produce a document which is full of high resolution large images around 60-100Mb each. The document is ok with small images, but with the large ones I get the error

```
 ! Unable to read an entire line---bufsize=200000.please increase buf_fize in tekmf.cnf.**ERROR** file ended prematurely Output file removed.
```

The problem is I do not get the output pdf file, otherwise regarding some advices I would have ignored this error.

So how can I place this sort of figures in my document?

Comment: Can you reduce the file size of the images? 60 MB to 100 MB is really large, most likely the amount of detail included in the image will not be visible, but the PDF will be really painful to handle (taking a long time to transmit and display).

Comment: @Jake It sounds pretty irrational, but these figures contain data which will be lost if I resize them.My only option now is finding a way to place them in the document and get the output!

Comment: What format is the image in? Do you mind to upload one of such images so we can play around with it?

Comment: @Argo the format is .eps, I cannot upload them before their official publish unfortunately

Comment: You could try compiling your document with `lualatex` instead of `pdflatex`. `lualatex` dynamically increases the memory size.

Comment: What program is giving the error? if you are using latex/dvips/ps2pdf or latex/dvipdfmx or something then tex does not need to read the file at all (it will by default to read the bounding box, but it does not need to) if you are using pdftex tex needs to read the image, but can't read eps

Comment: @Jake it's not main mem it's the buffer to hold a single line

Comment: Yes as I say in my answer the numbers need to be the coordinates of the image in your file 0 0 100 100 was just a test to see if that avoided the buffer overrun. 0 0 100 100 specifies a 100pt square at bottom left of the image, which probably is not what you really need

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I got the point when I re-read your answer. Tnx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LaTeX needs to know the amount of space to leave (and that is all it needs to know about the EPS file) the actual file inclusion happens later in the dvi driver)

An EPS file should have a comment of the form

```
%%BoundingBox: 111 222 333 444
```

where the numbers give the coordinates of the bottom left and top right corner.

Your file must have a very long line before that comment.

If you tell LaTeX the size then it does not need to open the EPS file at all.

```
\includegraphics[bb=111 222 333 44]{filename}
```

will specify the bounding box directly (overriding any specified in the file) this suppresses the search for the BoundingBox comment.